# ffmpeg-python trim why not concat

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to split the video, do some logical processing, and finally merge it

```py
import ffmpeg

info = ffmpeg.probe("test.mp4")
vs = next(c for c in info['streams'] if c['codec_type'] == 'video')
num_frames = vs['nb_frames']
arr = []
in_file = ffmpeg.input('test.mp4')

for i in range(int(int(num_frames) / 30) + 1):
    startTime = i * 30 + 1
    endTime = (1 + i) * 30
    if endTime >= int(num_frames):
        endTime = int(num_frames)
    # more more
    arr.append(in_file.trim(start_frame=startTime, end_frame=endTime))

(
    ffmpeg
        .concat(arr)
        .output('out.mp4')
        .run()
)
```

I don't understand why this is happening

```
TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream; got <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a little too late but you could try

```
.concat(*arr)
```

This worked for me with a list of defined start- and endframes